# Struts2 passing data in different ways

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack

I have been given the following code of a JSP page that uses the Struts2 framework

```
<s:form id="crud" action="crudmerge" namespace="templates">
    <s:hidden name="crudMode" />
    <s:hidden name="item.id" />    
    ...    
    <s:if test="crudMode == 1">             
            ...             
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <s:if test="%{version != null}">                
            ...             
        </s:if>
        <s:else>                
            ...             
        </s:else>
    </s:else>
</s:form>
```

in the action class that results in this JSP page, there is the following methods (among others): `getCrudMode()`, `getItem()`, and item has a method called `getId()`.

I understand how struts2 will use those methods to fill in the `<s:hidden>` tags. I'm having problems however with the following line:

```
 <s:if test="%{version != null}">
```

First, I thought this worked the same as the other two, and Struts2 would run the `getVersion()` method of the action class. However, there is no field called `version` and no method `getVersion()`. There is also no `<s:set name="version">` variable tag in the JSP. What could possibly be the point of this code? Are the `%{}` really necessary?

It is possible this is legacy code that needs to be removed, but I'm not sure what the difference is between the first two `crudmode` and `item.id` and the latter `%{version}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `test` attribute of the `s:if` tag you don't need to put `%{}`. This abbreviation is used to mark the scope of OGNL expression and removed before evaluation. While evaluating it's searching for variable `version` in the `valueStack`. The action object is on `top` of the `valueStack`, so if it finds a property with the name `version` it will execute `getVersion()` to return a result. If it didn't find the `version` at the action it will continue to search the whole `valueStack` until it find the property with the name `version`. More or like the same is described in the [documentation](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl-basics.html).

> XWork has a special OGNL PropertyAccessor that will automatically look
>   at the all entries in the stack (from the top down) until it finds an
>   object with the property you are looking for.